# Update column in another table with trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I would like to update a column in another table with the code below but I get a error that the trigger is invalid.
Whats wrong with it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_PAYMENT
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PAYMENT
  for each row

begin
  update PAYMENTTYPE PT
  set PT.PAYMENTTYPECOLUMN = PAYMENT.PAYMENTTYPECOLUMN
  where PT.ID = :NEW.ID and PT.ID2 = :NEW.ID2;

end UPDATE_PAYMENT;
```

Comment: what value of `= PAYMENT.PAYMENTTYPECOLUMN`? I dont see anything link with `PAYMENT` table in your query

Comment: In the 2nd line I'm refering to the PAYMENT table right?

Comment: I think you need to use NEW in place of PAYMENT in `set PT.PAYMENTTYPECOLUMN = PAYMENT.PAYMENTTYPECOLUMN`

Comment: And also: don't do this! Don't put DML inside your trigger. Instead, create a procedure that handles the update or insert, and then executes the update. You have lots more control this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your trigger you refer twice to `PAYMENT` columns by `:NEW.`, and this is correct, while the third time you use `PAYMENT.`, which is wrong.
The trigger should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_PAYMENT
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PAYMENT
  for each row
begin
  update PAYMENTTYPE PT
  set PT.PAYMENTTYPECOLUMN = :NEW.PAYMENTTYPECOLUMN   -- <------ HERE
  where PT.ID = :NEW.ID and PT.ID2 = :NEW.ID2;
end UPDATE_PAYMENT;
```